# Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight Validate xml by xsd schema

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8, xsd, windows-phone, xsd-validation

I'm using Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight. I have xml document and xsd schema. But I could not find solution to validate xml by xsd schema.

*XmlReaderSettings doesn't contains definition for Schemas property...
*For 8.1 exist https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb340331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx   but in 8.0 Silverlight XDocument doesn't contains definition for method Validate.

May be exists any third party solutions? Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not completly sure if this will help you (i posted this answer on another question too).

---

My original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770817/using-xsd-files-in-winrt-projects/33522151#33522151)

Ok this question is very old but in case others are having the same question / problem as i did, here is a (not completely free) solution:

1. Download the xsd2code plugin (https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) / or with the VS tools downloader
2. Register for a 15 days trial (you could also buy it)
3. Import the .xsd files in your project
4. Right click on them (one after one) and select "run xs2code"
5. (Here is the awesome stuff!) As target framework choose WinRT **(or in your case Silverlight)**
6. Generate the code and be happy!

Sadly i only found this tool (which has only a free 15 days trial) which was capable for doing this (generating code for WinRT / UWP / WinPhone)